# How can I connect Ubuntu 14.04 to my wireless printer canon MG5520

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, printing, canon

The problem I have is the connection with my Canon Wireless Printer MG5520. I made sure it is in the right connection. I even read some other questions here, trying to see if the answers will help me, but they didn't work.

Ubuntu recognizes my printer but the problem is once setting it up. Specifically when it's looking for the drivers, it will either say:

> "CUPS server error" [through "Printer settings"]
>
> "Failed to load"  [when you go through the settings on the corner].

**Please help!**

I need running and working properly before Fall semester starts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you open a terminal and do `lpinfo -v`and hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key; if you see the canon recorded there, then it should mean it is talking ok to the router;

use the Canon drivers; so go here and look for **MG5500 series IJ Printer Driver Ver.4.00 for Linux (debian Packagearchive)** click to download and **SAVE** it and it should end up in your Downloads folder as cnijfilter-mg5500series-4.00-1-deb.tar.gz

open a terminal; copy each command below; paste into the terminal; hit the ENTER key

```
cd Downloads

tar -zxvf cnijfilter-mg5500series-4.00-1-deb.tar.gz

cd cnijfilter-mg5500series-4.00-1-deb

sudo ./install.sh
```

that last command is the install script; watch as it runs as it will ask you questions; we hope all goes well

Comment: Thank you so much and sorry not to answer until now